# Bigquery SELECT * FROM table where column = 'string' not returning any values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I run the following query in bigqeury I am getting no results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raw.bicc_customers WHERE sub_type = "SUD"
```

I don't get any results

However, when I run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raw.bicc_customers WHERE sub_type LIKE "%SUD%"
```

I get results. The field that I'm looking for is SUD with no spaces, I don't understand why I need wildcards to find it. What am I missing?

EDIT:

So in the table the column is actually "SUD" - How would you find this without wildcards?

Comment: Is it possible that "SUD" has spaces or hidden characters around it?

Comment: Are you certain there aren't any spaces/special characters before or after `SUD`?

Comment: Try running `LENGTH()` on the returned values from using the `LIKE`.  You'll probably discover they have more than 3 characters.

Comment: What data type is sub_type? Is it possibly a char, autopadded with spaces?

Comment: Note that the equivalent of `LIKE "%SUD%"` is not `= "SUD"`, but `CONTAINS "SUD"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in the table the column is actually "SUD" - How would you find this
>   without wildcards?

Option 1 - escaping double quotes - see [Escaping special characters in strings](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#escaping) for more details

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM raw.bicc_customers 
WHERE sub_type = "\"SUD\""
```

Option 2 - using single quotes

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM raw.bicc_customers 
WHERE sub_type = '"SUD"'
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't add a comment, because I'm too new.

But try doing this query to help you determine what's wrong.

```
SELECT LENGTH(sub_type ) FROM raw.bicc_customers WHERE sub_type LIKE "%SUD%"
```

If you see that all the length values are greater than 3, that means you have some white space characters around it.

You can also do this to check:

```
SELECT LENGTH(sub_type ) FROM raw.bicc_customers WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(sub_type)) = "SUD"
```